# How do I extend a specific array type such as [Float]?

Tags: swift

I've implemented the following to add functionality to [Float]

```
extension CollectionType where Generator.Element == Float, Index == Int, Index.Distance == Int {
    func sum() -> Float {
        return self.reduce(0,combine: +)
    }
    var addThem:Float {
        return self.reduce(0,combine: +)
    }
}
```

This seems to work, so I can now do this

```
let x:[Float] = [1, 2, 3]

x.sum()         // 6
x.addThem       // 6
```

All is good.

But when I added this to the extension

```
 func doesSomething() {
    var data = self
    let background = [Float](count: self.count, repeatedValue: 0)
    // Compiler does not like this statement
    data = background
}
```

Playground complains that "[Float] is not convertible to Self."

When I change the code to this

```
     let background = [Generator.Element](count: self.count, repeatedValue: 0)
```

Playground responds with "Cannot call value of non-function type [Float.Type]."

And then I tried this

```
     let background:[Generator.Element] = [Float](count: self.count, repeatedValue: 0)
```

which gives the same "[Float] is not convertible to Self" syntax error when I assign `data = background`.

What do I need to do to assign a `[Float]` or an equivalent to variable `data` and what is `self` in the above extension?

Comment: Since self is just a collectionType, which is a protocol, the actual type of self is not guaranteed to be an Array. A collectionType can be Array or a Dictionary or any other type which conforms to CollectionType.

Comment: Can't you do `var data = self as! [Float]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28288619/2303865

Answer (score 0):

As previously mentioned, you can do this to sort of get it to work:

```
func doesSomething() {
    var data = self
    let background = [Float](count: self.count, repeatedValue: 0)
    // Compiler does not like this statement
    data = background as! Self
}
```

Though this will only work if the Collection happens to be a Float array.

I don't believe you'll be able to initialized the specific type of the collection because (as far as I know) There are no "required" initializers in the collection protocol.