# Extending Collection of FloatingPoint

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm trying to extend a Collection of FloatingPoint-conforming elements to work out an average.

```
extension Collection where Element: FloatingPoint {
    func sum() -> Element {
        return reduce(0, +)
    }

    func average() -> Element {
        return sum() / Int(count)
    }
}
```

`sum()` works fine but `average()` has an error.

> Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'Self.Element' and 'Int'

I'm not sure why this is. `Self.Element` is a `FloatingPoint`. I would expect to be able to divide this.

(I'm also aware that there's a divide-by-zero issue, but I'll fix that later.)

Comment: @Leo: In my opinion this question is very different from the one that you linked to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288148/making-my-function-calculate-average-of-array-swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You average didnt work because you were trying to divide some `FloatingPoint` type with integer. Use `Element(count)` to create new element of same type to divide.

```
  extension Collection where Element: FloatingPoint {
      func sum() -> Element {
        return reduce(0, +)
      }

      func average() -> Element {
        guard !isEmpty else { return 0 }
        return sum() / Element(count)
      }
    }
```

And this works because `FloatingPoint` protocol declares following initializer,

```
public init(_ value: Int)
```

This works with Swift 4.1, since count is Int. For earlier versions of Swift use,

```
  extension Collection where Element: FloatingPoint {
      func sum() -> Element {
        return reduce(0, +)
      }

      func average() -> Element {
        guard !isEmpty else { return 0 }
        return sum() / Element(Int(count))
      }

  }
```

Comment: I assume that you tested this with Swift 4.1/Xcode 9.3 beta. In earlier versions you'll need `Element(Int(count))` because the `count` is not necessarily an `Int`.

Comment: Your code gives me the following error: `Cannot invoke 'Element' with an argument list of type '(Self.IndexDistance)'` Do you know what's with that?

Comment: @dvp.petrov you can add a constraint to the Collection `where IndexDistance == Int, Index == Int`

Comment: You can simply use `Element(count)` if you extend Array

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm not a fan of extending `Array`, because it leaves `ArraySlice` in the dark, and it's really useful to have the same operations available to both

Comment: @Alexander Anyway This won't work when extending collection (Swift 4)  if OP doesn't constrain also  the IndexDistance and the Index type to Int

Comment: @LeoDabus Indeed, no disagreement

Comment: This works with Swift 4 since, count is Int in Swift 4 is wrong. You mean "This works with Swift 4.1 since, count is Int in Swift 4.1 for Swift 4 or earlier  use following,"

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus Done, If you see anything wrong with this, just write it here. :)

Comment: @Sandeep Not wrong but you can check the link I posted above. You can extend Numeric protocol for the sum to extend all numeric types and for the zero division add an isEmpty ternary condition