# how to add all integer in an array in swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, loops

I have an array with some integers in it, I need to sum them up and then compare. My code works perfectly in swift 2.

```
var sumedArr:[AnyObject] = textfieldarray.reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1})
print(sumedArr)
```

I'm getting this error now.

> "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: so... what is `textfieldarray`?

Comment: Your code works for me when using an array of ints to represent `textfieldarray`.

Comment: I just tried it in a playground with `let textfieldarray = [5,6,7,8]` and all I had to do was remove `combine:` from the reduce call so I ended up with `var sumedArr = textfieldarray.reduce(0, {$0 + $1})`

Comment: or simply  `reduce(0, +)` method declaration `func reduce<Result>(_ initialResult: Result, _ nextPartialResult: (Result, Int) throws -> Result) rethrows -> Result`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288148/making-my-function-calculate-average-of-array-swift/28288619?s=1|43.9745#28288619