# How can I make a generic extension on all number types in Swift?

Tags: swift, numeric

I am adding a computed property in extensions for my personal use, but sometimes I need this functionality in all number type values, how can I stop myself of repeating codes?

***My goal is making just one extension for all number type.***

---

```
extension CGFloat {
    
    var powered: CGFloat {
        get { return self * self }
    }
    
}


extension Double {
    
    var powered: Double {
        get { return self * self }
    }
    
}


extension Int {
    
    var powered: Int {
        get { return self * self }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I’d recommend calling this “squared”, that’s the existing term-of-art

Comment: yes, thanks a lot! good naming!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can extend `Numeric` protoocol and return `Self`:

```
extension Numeric {
    var powered: Self { self * self }
}
```

---

```
CGFloat(3).powered // CGFloat 9
2.powered          // Int 4
2.5.powered        // Double 6.25
Decimal(5).powered // Decimal 25
```

Note that this is possible because [Numeric](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric) protocol requires that the types that conform to it to implement `*` and `*=` operator functions.

Comment: thanks, what about `SignedNumeric` do I need this as well?

Comment: `SignedNumeric` is more resctrictive. `Numeric` with extend signed and unsigned types as well as `FloatingPoint` types and `Decimal`

Comment: `SignedNumeric` will extend all `FloatingPoint` and `SignedInteger` types. [Protocol SignedNumeric](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/signednumeric)

Comment: @swiftPunk `CGFloat` and `Decimal` conforms to `SignedNumeric` as well

Comment: I tried any possible number type, all working fine with `Numeric`, it covers everything.

Comment: @swiftPunk yes it covers all numeric types. You will have a hard time when trying to use the division operator. If you need only addition you can extend `AdditiveArithmetic` protocol  [Making my function calculate average of array Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28288619/2303865)